# How to twist the curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a simple curve and i want to twist. Selected the end point and press Ctrl+T to tilt, instead the curve to be rotate the direction of the curve is rotated. With the proportional editing on i try to rotate also. For me did not work. I tried to change the handle to aligned still nothing work. Any suggestion or help how it works.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more control points in order to achieve what you are looking for, using proportional editing. Try selecting all and subdivide the curve a couple of times, or just the portion you want to twist. Then select the last control points (as you have already done in the gif) activate proportional editing and rotate.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: i try dividing it did not work